# DataTables + input checkboxesdon't work

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I have some checkboxes that work fine, but when I try to program their value in the following listener I can only check/uncheck the boxes via clicking on the table row, and not the checkbox:

```
$('body').on('click', '#sourceTable tbody tr', function() {

var r = dTable.fnGetData(this);
var boxId = r[2].substr(r[2].indexOf("id")+4, 7);

if (document.getElementById(boxId).checked){   //checked is true
    document.getElementById(boxId).checked=false;   //uncheck the box
}
else{
    document.getElementById(boxId).checked=true;   //check the box
}
});
```

Any idea how I can do both?

EDIT: With changes advised in answer below looks like this, only checkboxes are clickable not rows, data isn't being read from DataTable row either:

```
$('#sourceTable tbody tr, #sourceTable tbody tr td input').click(function (e) {

e.stopPropagation();
var r = dTable.fnGetData('#sourceTable tbody tr');
var boxId = r[2].substr(r[2].indexOf("id")+4, 7);
//alert($(boxId).val());

if (document.getElementById(boxId).checked){
    document.getElementById(boxId).checked=false;
    var i = PEMSToDisplay.indexOf(r[0]);
    if(i != -1) {
        PEMSToDisplay.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
else{
    document.getElementById(boxId).checked=true;
    PEMSToDisplay.push(r[0]);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on the checkbox, the browser executes the default action on mousedown/mouseup (change the checkbox' state), then your handler is triggered correctly, and the checkbox changes state again.

See [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/a6Jmn/5/) :

```
$('body').on('click', '.foobar',  function(){
    var chk = $('#cb').prop( 'checked' );
    $('#cb').prop( 'checked', !chk );
    var after = $('#cb').prop( 'checked' );

    console.log('before :', chk, 'after :', after);
});
```

Notice how, when you click on the checkbox, the initial state is not the one you see - the browser has already altered the checkbox state before your `click` handler is executed.

One way to change your handler : if the target of the `click` event is the checkbox itself, don't do anything :

```
$('body').on('click', '.foobar', function(e){
    if( !$(e.target).is('#cb') ){
        var chk = $('#cb').prop('checked');
        $('#cb').prop('checked', !chk );
    }
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/a6Jmn/4/)

---

Note : I initially thought you could prevent the checkbox state change using `e.preventDefault()`, but it didn't work - tried it on `mousedown` and `mouseup` with no success.

Answer (score 1):

You need to target both the table row `#sourceTable tbody tr` and the checkbox, which I assume will be something like `#sourceTable tbody tr td input`. Following this you will need to stop the click event from bubbling up the DOM tree from the input to the table row, triggering both, by using stopPropagation.

```
$('#sourceTable tbody tr, #sourceTable tbody tr td input').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    ...
```

You will also need to replace `this` with `$('#sourceTable tbody tr')` as `this` could be either the row or the checkbox.

**Edit**: As per the comments, this would be better as:

```
$('#sourceTable tr, #sourceTable input').click(function (e) {    
    e.stopPropagation();
    var r = dTable.fnGetData($(this).closest('tr').get(0));
    ...
```

Comment: @gjw80 Please can you provide an example of your mark-up as this worked for me with a simple table containing a check-box input.

Comment: `var r = dTable.fnGetData('#sourceTable tbody tr');` should be `var r = dTable.fnGetData($('#sourceTable tbody tr'));`, does this help?

Comment: You can also simplify your selectors by using `$("#sourceTable tr, #sourceTable input").click(function(e) {` see example here (http://jsfiddle.net/puh6G/1/)

Comment: Sorry, you can target the tr by using `$(this).closest('tr')` so `dTable.fnGetData($(this).closest('tr'));` should work.

Comment: Again, I missed that fnGetData takes an object not a JQuery object so adding `.get(0)` should solve that. I have updated my original post.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42417/discussion-between-jonathan-and-gjw80)